# How to show links only on App component not on child component in React using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have App component, Create Component and Join Component. I want to display links/navigation to access Create and Join component only on App component. Currently when I click on Create link and Join link I can still see those links.

This is my current setup.
App.js

```
function App(props) {
   return (
       <Router>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <Link to="/join">Join</Link>
               </li>
           </ul>

           <div>
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/create">
                       <Create />
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/join">
                       <Join />
                   </Route>
               </Switch>
           </div>
       </Router>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place them on a specific, like your "home" route. `Router` matches and renders routes *inclusively* so you will need to specify the `exact` prop since "/" path prefix matches ***all paths***.

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/"> // <-- only render when path is exactly "/"
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/join">Join</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Route>

      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/create">
            <Create />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/join">
            <Join />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you can place them on a "generic" route at the end of the `Switch`, so if the path *doesn't* match anything else above it then it'll render. The `Switch` *exclusively* matches and renders routes.

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/create">
            <Create />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/join">
            <Join />
          </Route>
          <Route> // <-- matches only if nothing matched above
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/join">Join</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```